# CSS3 animations do not work in XP?

Tags: css, animation, windows-xp

So I made a site that heavily relies on CCS3 animations, I would never do this for a client as I know it is risky but as its just a personal project I don't mind.

The animations work fine on modern browsers using Windows 7 and they seem to work on XP when using Firefox, they don't work at all on IE but again it's a small personal project so I do not mind.

Now when using the site on the latest Chrome with XP the animations work but not correctly.
When you click the div, the div flips over displaying information, but on Chrome/XP it just flips the div but just shows the same div, just backwards instead of showing the other div behind it.

Also when using Chrome/XP it shows some of the images backwards when you load the site up, which I assume is the animations not displaying correctly.

You can see the site here: http://www.dansteeds.co.uk/awipmapv2/

Any help or information is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there anything unavailable in chrome://gpu ? For `rotateX/Y`, it's "safer" to also alter the `z-index` of front and back side.

Comment: I wouldn't have thought that it's 'XP' that's the problem, it'll be the version of the browser that will be causing the behavior.

Comment: But it has only happened on Chrome/XP, I mean on some older devixes it doesn't work at all, but it still displays the original content properly, for instance the animation do not work on my iPad 1/Safari but it still displays the original images correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome uses gpu hardware acceleration to render 3d css.

type the following url into your chrome browser `http://chrome://gpu` and check for `3D CSS: Hardware accelerated`. If it isn't, it will instead use a kind of quasi-3d isometric projection.

I think the hardware acceleration might be disabled in your browser causing a bug in your animation.

:)

Comment: Right yeah, this is all new to me, the people having the issue say that the 3D CSS is unavailable, so thats why it messes up then?